# Grub Rescue help!

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

i am having issues loading my dualboot Windows 7 laptop. I am currently at the grub rescue prompt and this is what I get.

```
grub rescue> ls
grub rescue> (hd0) (hd0,6) (hd0,5) (hd0,1)
```

I work my way through each one with the `set prefix=` and then `set root=` I either get a unknown file system or for `(hd0,5)`I get get to the `ls boot`and finally this `./ ../`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Load the Ubuntu Live session from USB drive or DVD. Download the Boot-Repair (instructions are here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair , use 2nd option first), then launch it and select 'Recommended repair'. After this the problem should be fixed.
This problem happened to me when I upgraded Windows 7 to 10. I suppose Windows messes up the GRUB if you install it after Ubuntu.

Comment: I loaded it a while ago from a USB which I no longer have and the version is probably at least 2 years old. No DVD/CD either...Should I burn a more recent copy from another computer?

Comment: Yeah, just make another USB with new Ubuntu version, doesn't matter which flavor.